# Static IP address for AMPL 2 trial

Tags: ip, licensing

I ordered a trial version of AMPL 2 weeks ago and they sent it to me with a trial license tied to a specific IP address (x.x.x.13). I tried today to run the program, but I found out that my IP address has changed to (x.x.x.17).

Can I reallocate my IP address? Or is there any way to run the program again without requesting a license again? Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about software licensing.

Comment: Go to your SysAdmin. Ask them to put a DHCP reservation in for x.x.x.13. Then, switch to a static IP of x.x.x.13. The reservation will ensure no one else uses the IP. If someone still has the IP after the reservation, have the other host renew their lease.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about the local network IP, that is most commonly 192.168.1.X, you can change it on your router config.
For that, type one of these(whichever one works) in your URL window;

192.168.1.1
192.168.0.1
192.168.1.0
192.168.1.254

It's unlikely its anything else. The login is usually either admin/root, admin/no password, or simply leave both boxes empty. Google around to find DHCP/network range or something similar, the interface is specific to your brand of router.

If the IP doesn't start with 192.168.., then you'd have to contact your internet provider and ask them. It is however, very unlikely they'd change it back.

**And for future reference, the IP changed because you didnt pick the option of having a static IP with your ISP - give them a ring and they can easily change that for you!**

They might offer you some kind of proof which you could forward to the retailer.

Best of luck.

Comment: It worked as following: I went to 192.168.1.1 and then to Network --> LAN --> DHCP Binding --> added a binding between my MAC address and the IP address.

Answer (score 2):

Your external IP address is likely set by your Internet service provider with [DHCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol). There are ways to try to renew your IP address, and if you're very lucky you might get your old one back. The specific steps would depend on your operating system.

Really it is a mistake on their part to tie your trial to your IP address, when for most people those can change at any time.